# Getting and assigning form element values in a Javascript Module Pattern

Tags: javascript

I need to access all of the elements in a form using a `Module pattern`. In a nutshell, I want to avoid repetitive code and use only a single module for organization purposes.

How do I do this without calling the Anonymous function from the module it self:

Instead of writing like this: `FormData.LastName()`
I want to simply have it look like this: `FormData.LastName;`

Below is an example I tried:

```
'use strict';

FormData = (function() {

    var formElement = document.forms.signup;

    return {

        LastName: function(){
            return formElement.lName.value;
        },

        SendBtn: function(){
            return formElement.submitSignupForm;
        }
    };

})();
```

Make calls to the module and access it's internal object values without the need of `Global` and `exposure`.

```
FormData.SendBtn().addEventListener('click', function(e){

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = FormData.LastName();

    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

*Another variation:*

```
'use strict';

FormData = (function() {

    var formElement = document.forms.signup;

    var LName = function(input){

            return input.lName.value;
        };

    var SendBtn = function(input){

            return input.submitSignupForm;
        };

    return {

        LastName: LName(formElement),
        SendBtn:  SendBtn(formElement)
    };

})();

FormData.SendBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = FormData.LastName;

    e.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

Comment: You can define getter/setter for that. Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object.defineProperty

example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548687%28v=vs.94%29.aspx 
better docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

```
var Mod = (function(){
    var module, formElement;
    module = {};
    formElement = document.forms.signup;

    Object.defineProperty(module, 'LastName', {
        get: function () {
            return formElement.lName.value;
        },
        writable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return module;
})();
```

Comment: I get the following error when I implement the above code:

`Uncaught TypeError: Invalid property.  A property cannot both have accessors and be writable or have a value, #<Object>`

Comment: Yes looking at the documentation. By the way, those configuration are already set by default  right? I am also reading `Professional JavaScript for Developers. - Nicholas Zakas.` So the writable was preventing the variable from being written to? This is a good place to start, it works! Thanks a million!!